# Flutter no OAuth result from Magic Link only on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, oauth

I am using `magic_sdk: ^0.3.1` and `magic_ext_oauth: ^0.1.0` in flutter to implement a login.

This is the code I am using

```
try{
  Magic magic = Magic.instance;

  if (loginType == OAuthProvider.GOOGLE) {
    Logger().w('logging with google'); //working
    var configuration = OAuthConfiguration(
        provider: OAuthProvider.GOOGLE,
        redirectURI: 'magicauthentication://');
    Logger().w('logging configuration added'); //working

    var result = await magic.oauth.loginWithPopup(configuration);

    Logger().w('popup passed'); //not working

    Logger().w(result.magic!.toJson());
    var token = result.magic!.idToken;
    exchangeToken(context, token);
  }
} catch (e) {
Logger().e(e); //not working
}
```

This code works fine without any bugs on Android. On iOS it does not. I added loggers to check the executing lines. There are marked in the above code as working and not working.

Since I had to add `android schemas` to work on Android I also added `applinks` on iOS

[image]

What can be the problem here why it is not giving result only on iOS ?

Is there anything more that I need to add?

Comment: I could not find anything about applinks in magic documentation so maybe that's not something you should be worried about. Could you print this `result.magic!.userMetadata!.publicAddress` after `var result` and see the result. Lastly, try updating the AppleDelegate.swift. Add `import MagicSDK` after UIKit and in the main function add `Magic.shared = Magic(apiKey: "API_KEY")`. I am not sure it will work as it was given in the iOS implementation but might be worth a try. More info here- https://magic.link/docs/login-methods/social-logins/integration/oauth-implementation/ios

Comment: can you please add a link to pub.dev to check the exact version?

Answer (score 1):

as it is clear from the score section of it, it doesn't support multiple platforms, try the recent one.

[image]